# How to load web resources like scripts, image, etc from right location when adding CORS support to a web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have a asp.net mvc application "App1" hosted on my local IIS running on port 1066 and another mvc application "App2" hosted and running on port 1067.

My requirement is that App2 needs to post some data to App1's available post end-point and App1 must validate that data. If data is valid, the response will be of type text/html else responds with a bad request i.e. http statusCode of 400.

Also, both the applications are to be hosted on different domains.

To make a prototype of the above case, I have a hidden form in App2 and using jquery, I then trigger submit of this form that targets to the name of the iframe like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:1066/user/index" method="POST" target="iframe" style="display: none;" id="mainForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="value1" name="h1" />
    <input type="hidden" value="value2" name="h2" />
    <input type="hidden" value="value3" name="h3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And javascript on the same page is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').append("<iframe id=\"iframe\" name=\"iframe\" style=\"width: 1200px; height: 1000px; border: none; margin: 0 auto; display: block;\"></iframe>");

    $("#mainForm").submit();

});
```

The above code works as per the requirements i.e. the response from App1 is rendered in the iframe and all the resources in that response like scripts, images, css, fonts are loaded correctly in the browser.

But in order to read the http status code of the response, I can't rely on regular form submit. So, I decided to use ajax to perform the same post and changed the script in App2 as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').append("<iframe id=\"iembed\" name=\"iembed\" style=\"width: 1200px; height: 1000px; border: none; margin: 0 auto; display: block;\"></iframe>");

  var params = $('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http:// localhost:1066/user/index",
                data: params,
                crossDomain: true
            }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                
                $('#iframe').html(data);
            }).error(function () {
                alert("error");
            });

});
```

And to enabled cross domain request, although I'm on my local IIS, I added CORS support by adding following in App1's web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Based on my understanding of the CORS support, doing the following changes should result in getting the same response as if I have done a regular form submit above.

The response is rendered in the iframe but all the resources like scripts, css, images, fonts from App1 is not loaded correctly. Due to some reason, even though App1 is hosted on port 1066, browser is looking for those resources in `localhost:1067/Scripts/Vendor/respond.js?_=1406232120396` Same applies to all other resources which in my App1's _Layout.cshtml view is written with `@Url.Content("~/src")`:

_Layout.cshtml in App1:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Vendor/respond.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Vendor/require.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/App/Images/abc.gif")" alt="Loading..." />
</body>
```

The image from fiddler that you can see below says that the browser is looking for all the scripts, styles in the layout file above in App2 directory instead of loading it from App1's source.
Also, the request for `/Content/css` and `/bundle/modernizr` resources is 200 because App2 has bundles defined with the same name. Expected outcome is these must be loaded from `localhost:1066//`.

[image]

I'm not able to understand why is this happening only when I'm doing the whole process via ajax post. As the same source code works fine when working with a regular form submit without ajax.

- Am I missing something to setup in my local IIS due to which there is a mismatch of the ports above?
- Or Am I missing something to provide full CORS support from App1' application?
- Or is something missing in ajax request in App2 ?
- Or Is the above behaviour expected in a localhost development environment when using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue actually has nothing to do with CORS. In your first example where you POST to the `iframe`, the iframe is actually setting it's `src` to the POST url `http://localhost:1066/user/index`. So all of the resources (image, script, etc) references are *relative* to `http://localhost:1066`.

In the second example you are getting the same HTML *content* you used in the first example, but because you are just inserting it into the `iframe` directly, instead of loading it from `http://localhost:1066`, the resource references are for `http://localhost:1067` instead.

You can set the base path that is used for resolving relative paths by adding `<base>`. In this case you'd set the base to be the same as the folder of the file you are posted to in the first example: `<base href="http://localhost:1066/user/">`

MDN has more information on the `<base>` element: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fbase

Comment: i have added this base tag in the App1 master layout file. however, while doing a regular form post, the src of iframe is `""`. Even after adding the base tag, image is not loaded, it stills load from 1067 port location. However, scripts - requirejs, respond.js are loaded from right location but I get require is not defined, which used to work in regular form submit.

Comment: @Yoda can you provide a dump of the HTML that is in the `iframe` after your AJAX call?

Comment: [This is the link to the html](https://gist.github.com/siddharth-pandey/f7fb3e629a7d1a24d494) and I have modified my [App2 script to parse html like this](https://gist.github.com/siddharth-pandey/32d30f44c63caf862969)

Comment: I'll look into it. FYI, I don't think you want to be `eval`ing your JS like that. The javascript will end up running in the wrong document context (parent doc, instead of iframe). Also using `eval` to process http (not https) responses is a security risk.

Comment: ok I'll remove it. also due to 404 result for that image, nothing gets  added to iframe's html don't know why!! thanks. Please let me know if you find any issue in it.

Comment: Check out this jsbin I created with a mock endpoint to pull the HTML from another domain: http://jsbin.com/qeyom/2/edit?js,output. I'm able to set the `<base>` and it loads the image correctly. All relative path resources in that HTML *should* load using that base href.

Comment: Your demo works fine however the same concept is not working on my locally hosted two sites. I'm still trying different ways to solve this.

Comment: I think your `<base>` is incorrect. In App1 is `index` in the URL `http://localhost:1066/external/index` a folder or file? If it is a folder then your base should be `<base href="http://localhost:1066/external/index/" />` or if it is a file the base should be `<base href="http://localhost:1066/external/" />`. Otherwise your relative paths are going to be incorrect.